Disabling custom error pages in Tomcat 9 based appservice on Azure
I have a Tomcat 9 based app service on Azure (see my stack attached) that has an in-out of season usage pattern and I need to swtich it to a lower app service plan for the summer.

The app has been running perfectly on a B3 sku plan until season started, when it was switched to a P1V3. So far so good.
Now I want to switch it back to B3 for the 'hibernation' period because it's more than 50% cheaper and more than enough for the hibernation requirements. Cost-cutting at it's most common sense.
However Azure does not allow it with the message "
The target sku ('Basic') does not support CustomErrorPages, please delete all custom error pages before making this change."
The error pages setup in Az is as following: 
I cannot remove these 3 entries, which have also appeared on another already running B3 webapp, using same stack, with no custom error pages, and on which Az is urging me to upgrade to a premium plan (see below). Which I most certainly do not need or want to.
I have tried to set and remove the custom error pages, hoping that some default was assumed at some point and I wanted to make the dis-configuration/removal of the custom error pages explicit.
I've been searching the 'net for a week now for a solution to now avail, copilot says of a solution that applies only to ASP.NET based webapps. Meanwhile the costs are adding up for nothing, my webapp is mostly idle, but I need to keep it going for the users to be able to access their account data until season starts again.
What am I missing?

Since the B3 plan does not support Azure portal-defined custom error pages as it need premium plan, configure custom error pages directly within the Tomcat application by editing the web.xml file. This approach will work independently of the Azure App Service plan.
 <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/file_not_found.html</location>
 </error-page>


Add these lines to the web.xml configuration file that redirects all the Tomcat 404 errors to the defined page.

The custom error pages (file_not_found.html and error.html) exist in the appropriate location within the web application.


MyWebApp/
├── src/
│   └── main/
│       ├── java/
│       │   └── com/
│       │       └── example/
│       │           └── mywebapp/
│       │               └── App.java
│       ├── resources/
│       └── webapp/
│           ├── WEB-INF/
│           │   ├── web.xml
│           └── error_pages/
│               ├── file_not_found.html
│               └── error.html
└── pom.xml


Here I have tested the application by triggering 404 and 500 errors to check that the custom error pages are being displayed correctly.


If budget is the issue, you can Auto/manual scale your instance.

To Downgrade your plan, Go to Scale up(app service).


There was a clear document on this please check here for more insights. If it doesn't work, please recheck your configuration and add more detail to your original question.


Re-posting the comment to your answer that got removed: I have tried your suggestion but it had no effect on the outcome. I have added error pages mappings in my web.xml and checked that they trigger correctly. The three entries for 403,502 and 503 are still in the Az error pages config and I cannot remove them due to 'delete' command greyed out (see my original post). Downgrading ASP to B3 results in  "The target sku ('Basic') does not support CustomErrorPages, please delete all custom error pages before making this change." What other details should I add?

Hi @VictorC., I understand that what you want to convey but here we able to delete CEP in the app service please confirm me that same you have done from your side. Once it is deleted you can be able to configure CEP through web.xml check here for linux and windows.

No, the 'delete' commands on the rows are disabled as well as the 'save' command on the CEP. I have tried to set custom error pages and saved the setup and then cleared the entries and saved the setup. No result. The entries are "Not configured", cannot be deleted and downgrade fails with "please remove custom error pages" requirement.

Once deleted, it will be permanently removed from the internal setup. If the issue persists, please reinstall the entire setup, as you cannot enable it when downgrading.

A new installation of the app was possible on B3, however that involves a pretty large amount of storage data (and I don't mean the database) to be migrated into the new app as well as the domain and a host of other resources. This is not actually a solution, but rather a workaround, and not an easy and straightforward one in my setup. A solution is explaining why is the "custom error pages" requirement enforced even if there is none configured, a way to remove the CEP and whihc will allow a simple ASP change and app restart.

There might have residual settings or like metadata that associated with CEP that were not visible in the Azure portal but will present in the backend configuration.

Eventually I ended up reinstalling the app on B3 migrating into the new webapp all necesary resources, switched DNS to the new instance once started, then stopped the previous one, which I kept stopped for a few more days untill I noticed that it still incurs costs, after which I deleted it along with it's ASP. Costs reduced by more than half now during off-season.
I would still like to understand why Az concluded that my app used custom error pages even if I am convinced that it didn't, which prevented a simple scale-down operation, and also what could I have done to make this change without the hassle of migrating everything into new webapp and ASP instances.
